# Replacing the content of a column in python

Tags: python, csv

I have multiple .csv files and I combined them in single .csv file with the use of python programming.

Now I need to automate the process of replacing the content of one column in a .csv file with the use of python. I can also open the .csv file using Notepad and replace the content of the column but the file is very huge and it is taking a long time.

```
Name                          ID                                                class  Num
"kanika",""University ISD_po.log";" University     /projects/asd/new/high/sde"","MBA","12"
"Ambika",""University ISD_po.log";" University     /projects/asd/new/high/sde"","MS","13"
```

In the above, I need to replace the content of ID column. The new content in the ID column should be "input".

This Id column is enclosed with 2 double quotes and has some extra spaces as well. Whereas other columns have only 1 double quote.

Is there any way to do it in python?

To combine multiple .csv files, the code is:

```
fout=open("out.csv","a")
for line in open("sh1.csv"):
    fout.write(line)
for num in range(2,21):
    f=open("sh"+str(num)+".csv")
    f.next()
    for line in f:
        fout.write(line)
    f.close()
fout.close()
```

Comment: Please read: http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html

Comment: That's not a csv file. Where are the commas?

Comment: @Wooble tab delimited csv perhaps?

Comment: Perhaps, but there are no tabs in what was posted, just spaces. Could be some kind of fixed-width format, I suppose.

Comment: no, i separated it with space so that you can understand. It is separated by commmas

Comment: Even if you were going to use Notepad `Ctrl-H` with `Replace All` would do the trick.  You might even be able to do it faster than an experienced Python programmer.

Comment: Replace all is takinga long time. I have 60,000 rows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As other people have indicated, normally one does use the `csv` module to read/write a CSv file from Python.

However, if the file you are mentioning is just like you posted, it is not well formed, and python's CSV won't be able to deal with it properly  - (bad usage of double quotes on the column you want to change).

Therefore it is worth treating your file as a text file, and make the changes in there:

```
with open("myfile.csv") as input_file:
   with open("output.csv", "wt") as output:
      output.write(input_file.readline())
      for line in input_file:
           parts = line.split('""')
           id = parts.split('"')[-1]
           output.write(parts[0] + id + parts[2])
```

Comment: I tried the code, but got an error. output.write(input_file.readline())----------
IOError: File not open for writing

Answer (score 2):

Try Python's `csv` module to read and write CSV files.

Comment: but how do i replace the content?

Comment: Simply read the original data from the input file and write the modified data to the output file, one row at a time.

Comment: -0.  The OP probably would not be able to handle such generic instructions.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression to remove it:

```
In [3]: re.sub(r'""Uni-\s*"([0-9]+)""', r'\1', '""Uni-  "38447484""', flags=re.I)
Out[3]: '38447484'
```

Answer (score 0):

You just want to remove ""Uni-   and " followed by a space.

change your code to

```
for line in f:
    line=line.replace('""Uni-','').replace('" ','')
    fout.write(line)
```

you get for example

kanika    "38447484"  MBA